# alternative to fadeToggle() in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have a `div` that I want to show/hide when clicking a button. The arrangement of the `div`'s is

```
<div id="someStats">
</div>
<div id="mainContent">
</div>
<div id="someOtherStats">
</div>
```

, meaning that from the `mainContent` I control whether to show or hide the two info `div`'s left and right. That gives me following problem: not only `fadeToggle()` makes one of the `div`'s transparent, its `display` attribute is set to `none`, which causes a displacement of the `mainContent` when fading out `someStats`. Are there alternatives to `fadeToggle()` without specifing two functions (or splitting a function like

```
if(div.isShown()){
   hide() 
}else{ 
   show()
}
```

? Or can I manipulate `fadeToggle()` in some way?

Comment: As the title mentions the name of the method is _fadeToggle_ not _toggleFade_, what do you mean by _"specifing two functions"_?

Comment: that was a misspelling. Changes it in the question and added explanation for "specifing two functions"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just animate the opacity

```
var target = $('#someStats'),
    opacity = target.css('opacity');

target.animate({opacity: (opacity==1?0:1)});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/MNhcU/

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uvupim/2/edit)**

```
statC = 0; // just a counter :)

$('#mainContent').click(function(){ 
  $('#someStats').fadeTo(300, statC++%2 ); // 1,0,1,0,1,0,.....
});
```

Slide toggle and FadeToggle will "detach" the element positions from your DOM, so you can try with `.fadeTo([time],[opacity]);` The element will just fade the opacity, and not be set as `display:none;` after the animation is done.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use toggle ( http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ ) and then you have control over each instance.

Fiddle forked from above - http://jsfiddle.net/hpaMV/

```
$('#some').toggle(function(){
    $('#someStats').animate({opacity: 1});
    ..anything else..
}, function(){
    $('#someStats').animate({opacity: 0});
    .. the opposite of the previous anything else..
});
```